# When Mouse is in Iframe the main page is not scrolling in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/jop93dhr/2/ , I have iFrame Content area inside my main page, but when my mouse is inside the iframe area, my main page is not scrolling , happens only in firefox. tested and working fine in chrome and safari.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    iframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');
    div_el = document.createElement('div');
    div_el.innerHTML = "<ul><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><li>foo</li><ul>";
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(div_el);
    <iframe id="iframeid" height="200px" src="about:blank">
        

            
            
     </iframe>
      <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <ul>
```

Comment: I tried using mozilla is working but it will have a bit delay when u try to scroll in iframe u try it out..... I scroll down to the end of iframe then it will delay about 1s - 2s  if u keep scrolling the main browser scroll will work..

Comment: @nicholas: When you are in middle of the iframe , try to scroll , only the iframe is scrolling, not the main page.

Comment: @nicholas you are correct, but I got this issue when i try to include the disqus iframe in my site, only in firefox, when the mouse is in disqus iframe, page is completely not scrollable

Comment: Sorry i don't get it when you include disqus in iframe only have this issue or existing already have this issue ?

Comment: @nicholas The issue seems with the nice scroll plugin which i used, found this link https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/322. thanks For the help.

Answer (score 3):

It's the default behavior of all browsers: if you have scroll in your iframe and mouse hover it, scroll priority will be given to this iframe.

Avoid having scroll in your iframe if you do not want this behavior (its content's height must be inferior than its height).

if you don't want to fix your iframe's height, you can create a transparent element covering it... but it's really dirty...

Comment: Try this in Chrome and Safari, The main page is completely not able to scroll even when my mouse is on the iframe content in firefox that is the issue

Comment: the issue seems with the nice scroll plugin which i used, found this link github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/322. thanks For the help.